# Python Multiprocessing Exit Elegantly How?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing
import time

class testM(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.exit = False

    def run(self):
        while not self.exit:
            pass
        print "You exited!"
        return

    def shutdown(self):
        self.exit = True
        print "SHUTDOWN initiated"

    def dostuff(self):
        print "haha", self.exit


a = testM()
a.start()
time.sleep(3)
a.shutdown()
time.sleep(3)
print a.is_alive()
a.dostuff()
exit()
```

I am just wondering how come the code above doesn't really print "you exited". What am I doing wrong? if so, may someone point me out the correct way to exit gracefully? (I am not referring to process.terminate or kill)

Comment: Actually, all this code should give you as-is is a NameError, because you're trying to instantiate the class during class creation. In other words: You probably want to dedent the last eight lines.

Comment: Note: this example code will fail on win32 because you have not protected the main script code with a guard clause:

`if __name__ == "__main__": ...

Answer (score 58):

The reason you are not seeing this happen is because you are not communicating with the subprocess.  You are trying to use a local variable (local to the parent process) to signal to the child that it should shutdown.

Take a look at the information on [synchronization primitives](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#synchronization-between-processes).  You need to setup a signal of some sort that can be referenced in both processes.  Once you have this you should be able to flick the switch in the parent process and wait for the child to die.

Try the following code:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

class MyProcess(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, ):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.exit = multiprocessing.Event()

    def run(self):
        while not self.exit.is_set():
            pass
        print "You exited!"

    def shutdown(self):
        print "Shutdown initiated"
        self.exit.set()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process = MyProcess()
    process.start()
    print "Waiting for a while"
    time.sleep(3)
    process.shutdown()
    time.sleep(3)
    print "Child process state: %d" % process.is_alive()
```

Comment: thx man, I was just looking up the API for VALUE, and i don't think it's mutable. This will work great in my app.
Thx a lot

Comment: Instead of waiting 3 seconds after you call shutdown (what if it takes longer than 3s to shutdown), you can join the process to quit exactly when the process is done -> process.join()

Comment: I just followed his original example: I wouldn't wait at all! (I'd do what you suggested).

Comment: wait if the process is stuck at some calls such as time.sleep()?

Comment: If you're planning on sharing the synchronization primitives, I would recommend using a message passing architecture instead.  In the past I've used RabbitMQ (message broker) and ZeroMQ (brokerless messaging library) for syncing parent and child processes.  On the other hand, it might be easier to either have a specific exit condition that the child process can detect without a management process, or shut the children down as part of the init.d management script (kill all child processes, etc).

Comment: `process` object has no function called `shutdown()`, `Manager` has it. How will this work?

Comment: `shutdown()` is no longer a method of `process`. The correct method is `terminate()` now. https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Is there any significance to the comma in `def __init__(self, ):`?