# Python, multiprocessing module, Process class, start method fail? Starts up an infinity of interpreters :|

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

This code starts up an infinity of processes and subsequently crashes my PC.

```
import multiprocessing

def f(process_name):
    print process_name, 'says hi'

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(None,f,'1',('1st',))
p1.start()
```

In the console i see '1st says hi' over and over again, in the task manager i see a bazzilion of interpreters starting - i ran this from inside PyDev eclipse and within the commandline - same result.

One other result i got was having a single python interpreter running (though dying and spawning another one really fast) so that i couldn't kill it within the task manager (handle invalid). It was eating up 100% of the processor though.

I am used to the java threading API, and the module multiprocessing claims to have a similar interface to the threading module, which is a copy of java's.

Why are the processes not dying? What am I missing to simply have this spawn a single thread, print the thing and die out?

Thx, you guys rule!

Comment: Why does the title say "threading module", and why the "multithreading" tag? Are you using `threading` somewhere that you haven't shown us?

Comment: that's simply a fail on my part - thx for pointing it out. i'll edit it right away

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to wrap up your initialization code in a `if __name__ == "__main__":` block.

Python executes your `__main__` module again after the fork starts the new interpreter. Anything not guarded by this construct will execute again. Which creates the effect you see.

Comment: Just for curiosity's sake, couldn't you also add a line like `for x in xrange(1):` and then the existing code would be beneath it?

Comment: @xxmbabanexx: The new interpreter will execute the same `for x in xrange(1)`, so that won't help. If you're trying to rely on `x` as a global variable that's shared by all processes, you _can_ make something like that work in some cases, but it never works in Windows, and there are cases where it doesn't work in POSIX, and there may be more cases where it doesn't work in 3.4, and so on, so… I won't explain how to do that, just don't do it.

Comment: thx! seems interpreted code is more different from the java compiled one that i thought.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the processes will die until you command them to do so with the `myProcess.exit.set()` command. I would edit your code to make it look like this:

```
import multiprocessing

def f(process_name):
    print process_name, 'says hi'

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(None,f,'1',('1st',))
p1.start()
p1.exit.set()
```

I wouldn't do this in larger programs though, as it can cause issues. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231599/python-multiprocessing-exit-elegantly-how) for more information about that. I would also recommend visiting the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) on this.

Comment: actually the processes do indeed exit themselves