# Implement Ctrl+C cancelling in python multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have been using the following methods to implement parallel child processes in python:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
pool.map_async(my_parallel_func ....)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

These tasks will run for several minutes. And I noticed that during this `pool.join()` blocking wait, I cannot press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> to cancel to main script. If I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, I'll get a stack print, the program is not stopped, but it will become a zombie process. I have to manually kill each of the subprocesses.

How do I make the program quit via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, and also terminate all child processes at the same time?

Comment: The subprocesses have to be told to shut down individually.  See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1231599/102937) for some guidance.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> kills only one process from the pool executing the async map; as soon as it is killed, the manager respawns the task using a new process. What you need to do somehow is to have a `except KeyboardInterrupt:` at the top level of `my_parallel_func`, and this could then by some special value to the main process tell that the whole process tree should die.

Comment: Putting exceptions into `my_parallel_func` won't work. It's actually the `pool.join()` that does the waiting. I'm wondering if this is possible without inter-process communication?

Comment: On my computer, linux 3.8, the ctrl+c kills 1 process from the processing pool... so it seems it varies...