# How to register "atexit" function in python's multiprocessing subprocess?

Tags: python, multiprocess, atexit

I have some subprocesses (using multiprocessing) and when they stop, each of them need do some final work. Something like the following, which did not work though...

```
import multiprocessing
import atexit

def final():
    print "final work"

def worker():
    print 'Doing some work'
    atexit.register(final)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

So how could I do this?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231599/python-multiprocessing-exit-elegantly-how which is similar to what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 15):

Processes started via multiprocessing do not exit normally and `atexit` functions get never called. You have to run cleanup stuff manually via a try/finally block, for example:

```
def worker():
    try:
        print('Doing some work')
    finally:
        final()
```

Or, if you really want to use `atexit` (see below for the drawbacks):

```
def worker():
    try:
        print('Doing some work')
    finally:
        atexit._run_exitfuncs()
```

---

Why don't subprocesses exit normally?

Technically, because [they quit via `os._exit()`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e04cd497aa41/Lib/multiprocessing/popen_fork.py#l76), skipping any cleanup job (including `atexit` functions, `__del__()` and weakref finalizers).

The reason behind this decision is that cleanup stuff risks being executed at the wrong time, in the wrong process. Most of the code that uses `atexit` (or other mechanisms) expects the code to be executed only once and only when the main interpreter exits (for example, one may use `atexit` to remove a temporary directory). By executing `atexit` functions every time a subprocess quits, you break this expectation and bad things may happen.

So, even though you can run `atexit` functions via `atexit._run_exitfuncs()`, avoid doing so, both because the function is undocumented and because you may not be the only user of `atexit` (other third party libraries may use it, and you may introduce bugs in their code).

Comment: This was an absurd decision.   atexit functions dont expect to be called from "main".   They expect to be called in the process in which they were registered.   so atexit merely needs to store the pid of registration in order to know whether they can be called.   Any modules which use atexit are now rendered useless inside a multiprocessing job... forcing me to use Popen instead and pickle their own state.   I actually forked multiprocessing just to put the proper cleanups back in.

Comment: I do agree with you very much Erik. I put together a better replacement for atexit, maybe you can take a look? https://github.com/kuralabs/multiexit

Answer (score 0):

You may use this `atexit` replacement that is multiprocess aware.

It will call only the functions registered by the process itself and not any other inherited my a parent process or anything.

https://github.com/kuralabs/multiexit