# Extending mp.Process in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, python-multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time as t

class MyProcess(mp.Process):

    def __init__(self, target, args, name):
        mp.Process.__init__(self, target=target, args=args)
        self.exit = mp.Event()
        self.name = name
        print("{0} initiated".format(self.name))

    def run(self):
        while not self.exit.is_set():
            pass
        print("Process {0} exited.".format(self.name))

    def shutdown(self):
        print("Shutdown initiated for {0}.".format(self.name))
        self.exit.set()

def f(x):
    while True:
        print(x)
        x = x+1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = MyProcess(target=f, args=[3], name="function")
    p.start()
    #p.join()
    t.wait(2)
    p.shutdown()
```

I'm trying to extend the `multiprocessing.Process` class to add a shutdown method in order to be able to exit a function which could potentially have to be run for an undefined amount of time. Following instructions from [Python Multiprocessing Exit Elegantly How?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231599/python-multiprocessing-exit-elegantly-how) and adding the argument passing I came up with myself, only gets me this output:

```
function initiated
Shutdown initiated for function.
Process function exited.
```

But no actual method `f(x)` output. It seems that the actual process target doesn't get started. I'm obviously doing something wrong, but just can't figure out what, any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: The `run` method in the base class is responsible for actually executing the target function. Since you've overridden that method, your target function never gets run.

Comment: So should I try and copy the original `run` method within the `while` loop of 'my' `run` method?

Comment: You could do that, but it's not going to help much. You need to modify your target function to periodically check the `exit` event.

Comment: Thanks, made it work! For future reference, I removed the `run` override, and added another argument (event) to the target method, which is now controlling the while loop.

Comment: BTW: Check out the meaning of `super` in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sane way to handle this situation is, where possible, to have the background task cooperate in the exit mechanism by periodically checking the `exit` event. For that, there's no need to subclass `Process`: you can rewrite your background task to include that check. For example, here's your code rewritten using that approach:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time as t

def f(x, exit_event):
    while not exit_event.is_set():
        print(x)
        x = x+1
    print("Exiting")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    exit_event = mp.Event()
    p = mp.Process(target=f, args=(3, exit_event), name="function")
    p.start()
    t.sleep(2)
    exit_event.set()
    p.join()
```

If that's not an option (for example because you can't modify the code that's being run in the background job), then you can use the [`Process.terminate`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate) method. But you should be aware that using it is dangerous: the child process won't have an opportunity to clean up properly, so for example if it's shutdown while holding a multiprocessing lock, no other process will be able to acquire that lock, giving a risk of deadlock. It's far better to have the child cooperate in the shutdown if possible.

Answer (score -1):

The solution to this problem is to call the `super().run()` function in your class run method.

Of course, this will cause the permanent execution of your function due to the existence of `while True`, and the specified event will not cause its end.

You can use `Process.terminate()` method to end your process.

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import time as t
   
   
class MyProcess(mp.Process):
    def __init__(self, target, args, name):
        mp.Process.__init__(self, target=target, args=args)
        self.name = name
        print("{0} initiated".format(self.name))

    def run(self):
        print("Process {0} started.".format(self.name))
        super().run()

    def shutdown(self):
        print("Shutdown initiated for {0}.".format(self.name))
        self.terminate()
   
   
def f(x):
    while True:
        print(x)
        t.sleep(1)
        x += 1


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = MyProcess(target=f, args=(3,), name="function")
    p.start()
    # p.join()
    t.sleep(5)
    p.shutdown()
```

Comment: This just makes the entire subclassing approach obsolete, since the ``self.exit`` exit Event is not listened to – as demonstrated by this code outright removing it.