# Struggling with multiprocessing in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to launch the receiver process. This is a class, which just receive data from socket. For minimum example it will just write rows in csv file.
I will send the exit signal through the pipe. After this signal the while loop in the separate process will end and this separate writer-process will finish.

```
import multiprocessing
from datetime import datetime
import time
import datetime
import csv
from multiprocessing import Process, Pipe


class CSVWriter:

    def __init__(self, pipe: multiprocessing.Pipe):
        self.pipe = pipe

    def write(self):
        with open(f'RTD.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, delimiter=',', fieldnames=['date'])

            while self.pipe.recv() != 'exit':
                writer.writerow({'date': (datetime.datetime.now())})
                time.sleep(1)
            print('exit csv')


pipe_receiver, pipe_sender = Pipe()


def write_csv(pipe):
    csv_writer = CSVWriter(pipe=pipe)
    csv_writer.write()


process = Process(target=write_csv, args=(pipe_receiver,))
process.start()

pipe_sender.send(input())
process.join()
process.close()
```

But, instead of my expectations, it doesn't create the file. Or, if i enter the wrong exit-key, it creates empty file.

I'm struggling with pipe around 2 days and can't understand the problem. I'll really appreciate for any information.

P.S. I'm using processes bc i need to receive the data from socket really fast (in example i just writes the data in file). So, i can't use threads.

Comment: Just to check, you're on a non-Windows, non-Mac system, correct? Without the import guard, `multiprocessing` does *terrible* things when operating in `'spawn'` mode (the default on both Windows and Mac, and the only option at all on Windows). Read [the guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#programming-guidelines) carefully; there's a lot of stuff that can go wrong if you ignore them.

Comment: Side-note: You say "I'm using processes bc i need to receive the data from socket really fast (in example i just writes the data in file). So, i can't use threads.", but unless you're omitting some heavy CPU usage, this looks like an I/O bound problem, and threads work just fine for those.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, i need to receive as fast as i can. The frequency can be up to 500 hz. So, even with clear receiving (without any different threads used) i have only as best as 300 hz.

Comment: I can get your code to 'work' under Windows if I put all the global variables inside an `if __name__ == '__main__':` and make a loop to take many `input()`s to send through the pipe until `"exit"`.

Comment: @i'm on Ubuntu. And i actually understood that i need to send input permanently. So, is it possible to avoid this recv() lock? I just need the while loop running endlessly, until i send only one exit msg

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1231599/python-multiprocessing-exit-elegantly-how) help at all?

Comment: @Mika: Adding interprocess pipes and locking increases the amount of I/O and system call overhead. Threads won't have the I/O overhead and will be able to use process-local locking. Threads are bad on the CPython reference interpreter if multiple threads are doing CPU-bound work, but it doesn't sound like that's your issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, your client opens the File and enters the `with`-statement, after which the file is supposed to be flushed to the disk and closed.
`pipe.recv()` blocks execution until data has been sent through the pipe, which only happens when you call `pipe_sender.send()`. you pass the result of `input()` straight into the pipe, and its result is recieved by `recv()`. When `input()` returns something else than 'exit', `recv()` will be called again, but this time, the parent process wont send anymore data, since the 'pipe_sender.send(input())' statement was only executed once. Therefore, `recv()` will block indefinitely, preventing the `with`-statement from being exited. Therefore, the write-buffer of the file is never flushed, and it remains empty. Additionally, your parent process calls `join()` afterwards, which leads to a deadlock:

The parent process is waiting for the child process to exit, which it cannot do, because it is busy waiting for data from the parent process with `recv()`.

The child process is waiting for the parent process to send data to it using `recv()`, which it cannot do, because it is busy waiting for the child process to exit.

When 'exit' is inputed, the while-loop is skipped altogether and the rest of your program executes as you expect; An empty file is created in this case too.

**The best solution would be to use threads(they are usually faster to be created than processes, and easier to handle since you can access the same variables and objects) or (because you call join and wait for the process anyways), do everything in the same program altogether**

Comment: I'm not sure, that threads are able to handle 500hz receiving stream. 
But if this is possible, i';; use threads ofc. 
In addition, is it possible to unlock recv() somehow? without receiving any data. just working process until the exit key arrived.

Comment: @Mika I dont think "unlocking" recv() is possible in pure python. There might be some OS-Specific API's you might have to use, for example, on windows, the subprocess could create a thread which calls Sleep and then CancelSynchronousIo. In order to do that, you have to take a look at the ctypes library and the documentation of whatever OS you are using (advanced). I think using threads is the better option. I don't see why threads couldn't handle a 500hz recieving stream.Side note: Python is a relatively slow programming language, at such speeds i recommend using a compiled language like c++.

Comment: I have a mini-project on C, written by separate programmer. But, it's kinda 'hard to communicate' with him. So, i can't really take care about workability of my project, with using his program, like C library